Reference for the subgroup structure of PGL2(q)
I have already read the material for the classification of PSL2(q), but I cannot find the full classification of PGL2(q), hence I cannot justify whether I am right or not. If anyone knows where I can find the reference, please let me know, thanks a lot

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

See also this post: Burnside classified all subgroups of $PSL(2,)$, and it is routine to use this to do the same for $PGL(2,)$. For this, see this post.
